# How to disable wifi autonegotiation on debian6.0

Tags: debian, wifi

I would like to disable automatic wifi negotiation on my 1000HE eeepc. WiFi Chipset is a ralink2860sta. I am using the non-free module and everything is working as intended except it tends to pick up first available access point everytime I boot up. I have various ways to configure wlan0 in /etc/network/interfaces but whatever I set up I would like to prevent negotiation or essid setting up.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if there is a "Debian" way to do it but there is the /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf file (maybe /etc/wpa_supplicant.conf) where you can specify which networks you want to use. For example:

```
network={
    id_str="stribnet"
    ssid="stribnet"
    priority=10
    proto=RSN
    key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
    group=CCMP
    pairwise=CCMP
    # I no longer use this key. It was last year's I think.
    #psk="/5w7Pb1K3X+8olncu6tQAICqm9cit6NAvqF86jOofWIDV6y/I+QN93SZV6z6"
    psk=91d55b029c84d8300dfb14930e345295d493ddf3c52d710288403e77bc5183a0
}

network={
    id_str="qb402"
    ssid="B402"
    priority=2
    key_mgmt=NONE
}
```

The priority options determines which network you prefer. This will try to connect to stribnet, then B402. If you want the old behaviour you can add this:

```
network={
    id_str="default"
    key_mgmt=NONE
    priority=-1
}
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to fine-tune my setup with your help.

Overtime, as the number of different AP I needed to connect to increased, I decided to use wicd to save me the hassle.